# How to get feature importance for each class in mutliclass classification with XGBoost?

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost

I have 6 different classes which I am doing multiclass classification on using both XGBoost and RandomForest.

What I want is to analyze which features are most important for a sample belonging to each class.

I know that there are two different ways of getting the feature importance using xgboost. First the built in `feature_importances_` variable which returns an array with importance score for all features.

Another way is to `from xgboost import plot_importance` which you can use to provide a plot through

```
 plot_importance(model = xgb, max_num_features = 20)
```

But all of these methods only return the most important features without respect to classes.

Is there a way to get the most important features for a sample belonging to each class?

Or would the solution be to create 6 different binary classifiers and try to analyze those feature importances instead?

Comment: I am having a similar doubt in a project of mine. All I could pull out was the crosstabs for each class and the Mean, std dev and few other statistics for each class.